# Update duplicate values in a view to make unique

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-update, unique

I have looked through previous answers but could not find how to update a view that has duplicate values in a column and make them unique.

For example I have a view with columns c1, c2, c3 and need to update values in c3 to make them unique as follows:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab - 99 | bc - 45 | ba - 12 |
| df - 45 | ef - 67 | ba - 12 |
| gh - 55 | sh - 23 | kj - 45 |

I need to update the values of "ba - 12" in column c3 to make them unique by adding a number or character before the dash so "ba - 12" becomes "ba1 - 12" or something similar

Results:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab - 99 | bc - 45 | ba1 - 12 |
| df - 45 | ef - 67 | ba2 - 12 |
| gh - 55 | sh - 23 | kj - 45 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions `row_number` and `count` will help. New `c3` becomes: if the record count within the window `(partition by c3)` is 1 then `c3` else `c3` decorated with the row number within that window.

```sql
create or replace view the_updated_view as
select c1, c2, 
    case when cnt = 1 then c3 
         else replace(c3, ' -', '.'||rn||' -') 
    end as c3
from 
(
  select *, row_number() over w rn, count(*) over w cnt
  from the_table
  window w as (partition by c3)
) t;
```